# Reference type (weak or strong) for for IBOutlet child viewcontrollers in a viewcontroller hierarchy?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

Sorry if this is a dumb question; I think I already know the answer for this but would like to confirm. For a while it's been Apple-approved to embed viewcontrollers within viewcontrollers (i.e. a viewcontroller hierarchy). Typically, with IBOutlet connections to objects within a viewcontroller I would use weak references since the container view would presumably own these items. Is this different for embedded viewcontrollers?

Answer (score 0):

If by embedded you mean as children of [UIContainerView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html) or UIPageView, so that you will be inflating them from the storyboard as `[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"blahblah"]` then you should make them strong and not even need to declare them as `IBOutlet` per se. But if they are connections that you drag from the storyboard to the code, then weak should be fine (but then I can't quite see this one, so you may need to give a bit more detail for better help).

Comment: Thanks for the reply; I wasn't thinking storyboard, but plain ol' UIViewController, I work mostly on non-storyboarded projects. The child UIViewController is set as the childController of a parent UIViewController.

Comment: The answer implies that the source of the vc (code or IB) makes a difference in how it should be declared.  What matters is not where one comes from, but where it goes.  If its added to a vc's childViewControllers array, then it gets retained there, and there's no need for a strong pointer.  That's true notwithstanding how the vc was built.

Comment: BTW, there is no such thing as a UIContainerView.